# Non-destructive (peek) parallel processing of MSMQ

Tags: c#, .net, parallel-processing, msmq

I have a MSMQ with hundreds of messages being sent to it a second.  To aid processing and provide high availability I am processing the queue over N computers. I have two services per computer, one is a Reader that reads off the queue, the other is a node that actually processes the messages. Note the nodes are arranged in a cluster for HA.

Currently my implementation "reads" off the queue which essentially removes the message from the queue.  This is fine in testing but should something happening to the processing nodes that message will be lost.

As such I think need to implement something like this:

- Peek off the queue,
- Send message to be processed by nodes
- Check result
- If successful, read (ie. remove) the message from the queue.

Currently I process messages in parallel using TPL but I am unsure how to achieve such a thing whilst also using peek?

**Note:**
I assume peek and then read on success is the best way to go here?

Comment: SWAG: Use an [internal transaction](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms978430.aspx#bdadotnetasync2_topic3b) to wrap reading a message from the inbound queue and sending it to a node work-in-progress (WIP) queue. (That's relatively expensive.) The message will always be on one or the other. That shifts the "issue" to where WIP queues are persisted, i.e. can they be recovered by another node, and how nodes track when they have finished processing a message. Would a WIP queue ever have more than one message in it for your application? What happens if a message is processed twice?